# Publish message to all users except sender

Tags: php, websocket, broadcast, symfony-3.4, phpwebsocket

I'm using GosWebSocketBundle (https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle) to send notifications/messages. I have referred the documentation and done with broadcasting message to all the subscribers of the common channel. But I don't want the sender to receive it's own message. Please help me.

```
public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $connection, Topic $topic, WampRequest $request)
{
//this will broadcast the message to ALL subscribers of this topic.
$topic->broadcast(['msg' => $connection->resourceId . " has joined " . $topic->getId()]);
}

public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $connection, Topic $topic, WampRequest $request, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible)
{
$topic->broadcast(['msg' => $event]);
}
```

Comment: I think the easiest way would be a broadcast to all and to have the client ignore its own messages

Comment: @Psi Please explain me with some pseudo code

Comment: I think you can figure it out yourself. The idea is to send a client identifier along with the message. When the client receives the message, he'll realize it was sent by him and ignore it. This way you don't need to split on the server side